# Running my own made android app on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hey I have made an qr scanner Android app and have made apk file. It runs smoothly on my phone but I wanted it to work on emulator such as BlueStacks. However it doesn't get install there. Any idea of how to make it work?

Comment: "doesn't get install there" .. what does that mean? Any error? Tell us what you have tried to install it on BlueStacks so we know what answers not to give you

Comment: Hey so when I try to install it on BlueStacks it keeps on loading and eventually a red exclamation mark appear on the icon of the app in BlueStacks window. Thus app doesn't install to be able to run on BlueStacks

Comment: Check your app api level.

Comment: Have you got camera attached in Blue stacks ???

Comment: Yeah I checked that by installing another app. Camera works fine in that

Comment: @Abhi yeahh that worked